# Not able to open files from HyperLink control in IE9 & above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am trying to open a file using hyperlink control, when I click on the link no action is getting triggered, but when I paste the file:/// path in IE browser directly the file is downloaded/opened, what could be the issue below is my href content and also one can check in JSFiddle at     http://jsfiddle.net/q76VB/

```
<a href="file:///C:/tempdel/NewTextDocument.txt" id="url">My Link</a>
```

Comment: Browsers handle the file-protocol (file:///) different. Did you try to link to a txt file on a (local) web server?

Comment: I think it will only work if the site is not in the Internet Zone but Intranet or Trusted Site.

Comment: @FabianMebus Yes I tried in local server with a text file but no luck.

Comment: @VitorCanova: My site is a intranet site itself and I added in Trusted zone and tried as well but no luck.

Comment: Well, what can I say. You are trying to majke user execute a program in his PC. I think it is triggering some security lock.

Comment: @VitorCanova Even I am suspecting on some security, but are there any settings to disable this security ? Also when I try to provide the file path url file:///C:/tempdel/NewTextDocument.txt in the broswer text file is opened, only when it is opened from HyperLink this issue is being faced.

Comment: I think it is because the origin. When you open in the address bar it is a complete user initiate action. In hyperlink the user can be tricked to think it will open anther page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the file on the server that is hosting your website?

Put the file in the same folder as your html files and change the link to this:

```
<a href="NewTextDocument.txt" id="url">My Link</a>
```